# How to add new related entity to exist main entity by navigation property in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have 2 entities, `Document` and `StoredFile`. Each one has its owned custom properties mapped to the database.

`Document` has 2 nullable properties with reference to `StoredFile` entity.

`Document` class:

```
public Guid Id { get; private set; }
public string Description { get; private set; }
public StoredFile? ResultFile { get; private set; }
public StoredFile? SourceFile { get; private set; }

protected Document() {}

public Document(Guid id, string description)
{
    Id = id;
    Description = description;
}

public void SetResultFile(string path, long size)
{
    var storeItem = new StoredFile(path, size);
    ResultFile = storeItem;
}
```

`StoredFile` class:

```
public Guid Id { get; private set; }
public string Path { get; private set; }
public long Size { get; private set; }
public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; private set; }

protected StoredFile() { }

public StoredFile(string path, long size)
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    Path = path;
    Size = size;
    CreatedAt = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    Stored = false;
}
```

Configuration:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Document> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(a => a.Id);

    builder
        .HasOne(a => a.ResultFile)
        .WithMany();
    
    builder
        .HasOne(a => a.SourceFile)
        .WithMany();
}
```

Creation of document:

```
var doc = new Document(request.ResearchId, description);
_db.Documents.Add(doc);
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Adding of result file to document:

```
var document = await _dbContext.Documents
                                       .Include(a => a.ResultFile)
                                       .SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == request.DocumentId, cancellationToken);
        document.SetResultFile(path, size);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

At first I save `Document` with null in `Files` properties into the database. After storing file to Amazon S3, I call `SetResultFile()` method to assign navigation property of file.

But after that I get an error

```
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23503: insert or update on table "documents" violates foreign key constraint "fk_documents_document_stored_files_result_file_id"



Failed executing DbCommand (8ms) [Parameters=[@p5='?' (DbType = Guid), @p0='?' (DbType = DateTime), @p1='?' (DbType = DateTime), @p2='?', @p3='?' (DbType = Int64), @p4='?' (DbType = Boolean), @p8='?' (DbType = Guid), @p6='?' (DbType = Guid), @p7='?' (DbType = DateTime)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
| UPDATE stored_files SET created_at = @p0, last_modified_at = @p1, path = @p2, size = @p3, stored = @p4
| WHERE id = @p5;
| UPDATE documents SET result_file_id = @p6, last_modified_at = @p7
| WHERE id = @p8; <s:Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command>
```

And in logs I see SQL instructions about update of `Document` (normally) but also about !update of `StoredFile` entity. Not insert!

But why if I have just added this new file entity to the EF Core context by navigation property?

I tried to add `StoredFile` entity to its `DbSet` before calling `SaveChanges`, and it has finished normally.

So question: do I have always to add new entity to the `DbSet`, or is there any possibility to add related entity by navigation property as f.ex. `ResultFile`?

Comment: You have missed important part - how you update entity.

Comment: Sorry, dont understand question exactly. When I assign new ResultFile to existed Document I just call method Document.SetResultFile and then call SaveChanges.

Comment: `Document.SetResultFile` interpreted by EF Core as Insert. For updating you have to `Include(x => x.ResultFile)` and then update ResultFile`s properties.

Comment: But in fact Insert is that I expect to see in sql instruction. But ef generate update for file entity when I assign new file to navigation property of exist entity of document

Comment: Please update your question with the complete exception, as well as the code you are using to create the document, call SetResultFile, and `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: Done. I've added exception text and more code samples. It's unnormally but you can see in logs UPDATE sql instruction instead of INSERT for File entity.